# parsing strings with Parse package

Tags: python, parsing

I am attempting to create a program with a console input and parse the text input.

```
import parse


while True:

    def parse_text(text: str) -> str:
        result = parse.parse(text)
        return str(result)

    answer = input('Which type of component do you need help with, an AHU or VAV?')
    name = parse_text(answer)
    if {name} == 'VAV':
        print('Ok, what VAV number?')
    if {name} == 'AHU':
        print('Ok, what AHU number?')
    else:
        print('Please specify AHU or VAV')
```

I have a feeling the function `parse_text` isnt returning a string, can someone give me a tip?

```
Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
========== RESTART: C:/Users/benb/Desktop/text_parse/parse_hvac.py ==========
Which type of component do you need help with, an AHU or VAV?AHU
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/benb/Desktop/text_parse/parse_hvac.py", line 13, in <module>
    name = parse_text(answer)
  File "C:/Users/benb/Desktop/text_parse/parse_hvac.py", line 9, in parse_text
    result = parse.parse(text)
TypeError: parse() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'
>>>
```

Comment: there's so many syntax errors it doesn't even look like python

Comment: which ones @SuperStew?

Comment: `parse_text(text: str) -> str` and `{name}`, and while not incorrect, `str(result)` is unnecessary

Comment: The first one is part of the type hints added in 3.5. But `{name}`.. I don't know what it is.

Comment: @SuperStew those are called function annotations and they are valid. Read more at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/

Comment: I think you mean PEP 484 https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: You are correct about PEP 484 being the current standard. It looks like PEP 3107 was the original convention, but was replaced by PEP 484. Either way, they can be helpful for providing type hints and self documentation. They avoid having to retype the parameters (like with sphinx notation in docstrings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parse` needs two arguments, look at https://github.com/r1chardj0n3s/parse

If the input function you call is the one provided by Python, why don't you just do

```
name = answer.upper()
if name == 'VAV':
    print('Ok, what VAV number?')
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, can you expand or post answer how to fix the issue? Sorry still learning...

Comment: See the edited answer. Also, what's the purpose of those curly braces in `{name}`?

Comment: That worked, the curly brackets were from documentation I was trying to follow.

Comment: One thing that sort of sucks the program loops thru to the very beginning..